# I need to get the min, max, avg of an Array List using Java

Tags: arraylist, java.util.scanner, average

The values come from a Junit test case or from a scanner, so the method has to work in all scenarios.  The array List looks something like this.

```
   Utah          5
   Nevada        6
   California   12
   Oregon        8
   Utah          9
   California   10
   Nevada        4
   Nevada        4
   Oregon       17
   California    6
```

I need to be able to calculate the average of, let's say, Utah. I know how to do something that finds the average. My biggest problem is knowing how to only get values from the names of Utah rather than just getting all of them.

> names=states values= numbers categories=what

you are calculating
here is the start of the method:

```
public static ArrayList<Double> summarizeData (ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Double> values ,ArrayList<String> categories, int operation)
```

Comment: Which JDK Version you're using?

Comment: I am currently using 8.  Although, I am not supposed to take many "shortcuts"

Comment: Then you should use streaming APIs which allows you to Aggregate List.